# Possible to download JPA repository in Vaadin as CSV file?

Tags: database, spring-boot, csv, jpa, vaadin14

Assume that we have defined a entity and it's connected to a database. Now we can access the database by using a repository.

```
@Autowired
private DataLoggRepository dataLoggRepository;
```

If I want to get all the rows from the database and download it. Then I can write this code:

```
List<DataLogg> dataLoggers = dataLoggRepository.findAll();
```

Now, how can I donwload the object `dataLoggers` as a CSV file in Vaadin in a proper way?

Comment: Use any CSV generate tools like OpenCSV

Comment: @Eklavya Thank you. Does OpenCSV works with Vaadin? Vaadin is web application framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see how to create a link to download a file:

```
Anchor csvLink = new Anchor(new StreamResource("file.csv",
                 () -> {
                     String csvString = ...// create the csv
                     return new ByteArrayInputStream(csvString.getBytes());
                 }), "Download CSV");

csvLink.getElement().setAttribute("download", true);
```

To create the CSV you have various options like OpenCSV or directly create the CSV from the SQL query.

Comment: Can I use a button instead? Your code does not work with Vaadin14

Comment: You could style the Link like a button. But you cannot use a button. What do you mean by does not work? I'm using that in my application. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Also see my answer as well.

Comment: `Can I use a button instead?` - yes, you can use the [FileDownloadWrapper](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/file-download-wrapper) add-on which will display a Button instead of an anchor link. I use this for all my downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
        // Download all data
        Anchor download = new Anchor(); // Add this to the layout
        loggerId.addValueChangeListener(e-> {
            String fileName = String.valueOf(loggerId.getValue()) + ".csv";
            List<DataLogg> selectedLogger = dataLoggRepository.findByLoggerId(loggerId.getValue());
            download.setHref(getStreamResource(fileName, selectedLogger));
        });
        download.getElement().setAttribute("download",true);
        download.add(new Button("Download", new Icon(VaadinIcon.DOWNLOAD_ALT)));
```

Function

```
public StreamResource getStreamResource(String filename, List<DataLogg> selectedLogger) {
        // Create a large CSV file in a form of StringBuilder and then convert it all to bytes
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        stringWriter.write("id, dateTime, DO0, DO1, DO2, DO3, AI0, AI1, AI2, AI3, loggerId, samplingTime\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedLogger.size(); ++ i) {
            DataLogg dataLogg = selectedLogger.get(i);
            String row = dataLogg.getId() + "," +
            dataLogg.getDateTime() + "," +
            dataLogg.getDO0() + "," +
            dataLogg.getDO1() + "," +
            dataLogg.getDO2() + "," +
            dataLogg.getDO3() + "," +
            dataLogg.getAI0() + "," +
            dataLogg.getAI1() + "," +
            dataLogg.getAI2() + "," +
            dataLogg.getAI3() + "," +
            dataLogg.getLoggerId() + "," +
            dataLogg.getSamplingTime() + "\n";
            stringWriter.write(row);
        }

        // Try to download
        try {
            byte[] buffer = stringWriter.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            return new StreamResource(filename, () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[] {0};
            return new StreamResource(filename, () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
        }
    }
```